# Jenkins abort downstream job when web button is clicked

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

As a Jenkins beginner, I am seeking the best way to abort downstream Jenkins job when a user hits Submit button on web. The job could either be in a queue or running when user hits 'Stop'.

While searching for possible options, I saw that Jenkins supports REST APIs as well as one can use curl but for that one needs to know the state of downstream job whether it's queued/running.

(Jenkins would need authentication as access is restricted, not sure how tokens work too)

Answer (score 1):

This is still a pending request: [`JENKINS-11257`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11257)

- [`jenkinsci/parameterized-trigger-plugin` Pull-Request 104](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-trigger-plugin/pull/104) could be a solution if you can modify and rebuilt your own Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin
- [This python script](https://gist.github.com/almiroshnich/734e31ba46cff18ec7a45b99cc791787#file-jenkins_postbuild_abort_downstream-py) could help
- you can try and experiment with [Jenkins: how to stop downstream projects when upstream is aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567089/6309) and its "kill" nuclear option.